# simplifying $\sqrt{x^2}$ in a limit, when $x$ tends to $-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Sorry but I am not that good at maths, but I have one simple question.

In a $\lim_{x \to -\infty}$, I want to take the $x^2$ out of a square root; after that, is it

$|x^2| = x$ or $-x$?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the absolute value of a number is always non-negative. Which one is positive, $x$ or $-x$?

Comment: Most probably you want to know this (?): $\sqrt{x^2} =|x| \stackrel{x<0}{=}-x$

Comment: Matti P, x is going to -oo 
I want to know |x²|=  x or -x, i want to know as x is going to -oo then shall we add the signe ( - ) or keep it positive?

Comment: C'est $-x$, qui est un nombre positif.

Comment: Thanks all, I got already the answer <3

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ tends to $-\infty$, then surely $x$ will be negative (eventually).

Now combine two basic things:

- the property: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \sqrt{x^2} = \left|x\right|$
- the definition: $\left|x\right| = \begin{cases} x & \mbox{if } x \ge 0 \\ -x & \mbox{if } x \le 0\end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you sir, so useful <3